# Checkbox list values only saying all unchecked?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to setup a definition so when the person selects the checkbox's they want, when they press the save button it prints whether its checked or unchecked. However, all of them are coming up as unchecked.

It's using Tkinter btw

I have tried using onvalue and offvalues in the checkbutton event but it does not work

```
def checker():
    global var_list
    var_list = [var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), 
    var5.get(), 
    var6.get(), var7.get(), var8.get(), var9.get(), var10.get()]
for var in var_list:
        if var == 1:
            print('checked')
        else:
            print('unchecked')


var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[0] + " " + web_1_date[0], 
variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[1] + " " + web_1_date[1], 
variable=var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[2] + " " + web_1_date[2], 
variable=var3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[3] + " " + web_1_date[3], 
variable=var4).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[4] + " " + web_1_date[4], 
variable=var5).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[5] + " " + web_1_date[5], 
variable=var6).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[6] + " " + web_1_date[6], 
variable=var7).grid(row=6, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[7] + " " + web_1_date[7], 
variable=var8).grid(row=7, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[8] + " " + web_1_date[8], 
variable=var9).grid(row=8, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[9] + " " + web_1_date[9], 
variable=var10).grid(row=9, sticky=W)


var_list = [var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), var5.get(), 
var6.get(), var7.get(), var8.get(), var9.get(), var10.get()]
```

It says everything is unchecked, even when i have checked every box in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you probably have an indentation error or something like that. I didn't modify your `checker` function but just added some of the variables that were missing from your code and it seems to work ok.

```
from tkinter import *



def checker():
    global var_list
    var_list = [var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), 
    var5.get(), 
    var6.get(), var7.get(), var8.get(), var9.get(), var10.get()]
    for var in var_list:
        if var == 1:
            print('checked')
        else:
            print('unchecked')

event_1_window = Tk()

web_1_title = ["title{0}".format(i) for i in range(10)]
web_1_date = ["date{0}".format(i) for i in range(10)]

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()
var3 = IntVar()
var4 = IntVar()
var5 = IntVar()
var6 = IntVar()
var7 = IntVar()
var8 = IntVar()
var9 = IntVar()
var10 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[0] + " " + web_1_date[0], 
variable=var1).grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[1] + " " + web_1_date[1], 
variable=var2).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[2] + " " + web_1_date[2], 
variable=var3).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[3] + " " + web_1_date[3], 
variable=var4).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[4] + " " + web_1_date[4], 
variable=var5).grid(row=4, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[5] + " " + web_1_date[5], 
variable=var6).grid(row=5, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[6] + " " + web_1_date[6], 
variable=var7).grid(row=6, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[7] + " " + web_1_date[7], 
variable=var8).grid(row=7, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[8] + " " + web_1_date[8], 
variable=var9).grid(row=8, sticky=W)
Checkbutton(event_1_window, text= web_1_title[9] + " " + web_1_date[9], 
variable=var10).grid(row=9, sticky=W)

button = Button(event_1_window, text="Check", command=checker)
button.grid(row=10,sticky=W)

var_list = [var1.get(), var2.get(), var3.get(), var4.get(), var5.get(), 
var6.get(), var7.get(), var8.get(), var9.get(), var10.get()]
```

Comment: Hmm yeah your solution seems to work perfectly the way i want. I feel its probably an indenting problem aswell as i had to swap loads of definitions around as it was all messy. I'll give it a shot. Thanks alot!

Comment: You're right, must've been some sort of weird ordering or indentation problem. I moved the code up to the top of my program and it worked perfect. Thanks alot!